# label empty or too long - python urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am having a strange situation:

i am curling urls like this:

```
def check_urlstatus(url):
  h = httplib2.Http()
  try:
      resp = h.request("http://" + url, 'HEAD')        
      if int(resp[0]['status']) < 400:
          return 'ok'
      else:
          return 'bad'
  except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError:
      return 'bad'
```

if I try to test this with:

```
if check_urlstatus('.f.de') == "bad": #<--- error happening here
   #..
   #..
```

it is saying:

```
UnicodeError: label empty or too long
```

what is the problem i am causing here?

**EDIT**: here is the traceback with idna. I guess, it tries to split the input by `.` and in this case, first label is empty which is the pace before the first `.`.

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing, it didn't throw any exception apart from one you've catched. What Python version are you using?

Comment: i am using python 2.7 @PankajSharma

Comment: I used the same. worked fine.

Comment: @PankajSharma in idle it is working fine. in real call, it is giving me the error above

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is your URL cannot properly be encoded as per the [`IDNA` rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), which govern how internationalized domain names are converted:

> The conversions between ASCII and non-ASCII forms of a domain name are
>   accomplished by algorithms called ToASCII and ToUnicode. These
>   algorithms are not applied to the domain name as a whole, but rather
>   to individual labels. For example, **if the domain name is
>   www.example.com, then the labels are www, example, and com. ToASCII or
>   ToUnicode *are applied to each of these three separately*.**
>
> The details of these two algorithms are complex, and are specified in
>   RFC 3490. The following gives an overview of their function.
>
> ToASCII leaves unchanged any ASCII label, **but will fail if the label
>   is unsuitable for the Domain Name System.** If given a label containing
>   at least one non-ASCII character, ToASCII will apply the Nameprep
>   algorithm, which converts the label to lowercase and performs other
>   normalization, and will then translate the result to ASCII using
>   Punycode[16] before prepending the four-character string "xn--".[17]
>   This four-character string is called the ASCII Compatible Encoding
>   (ACE) prefix, and is used to distinguish Punycode encoded labels from
>   ordinary ASCII labels. The ToASCII algorithm can fail in several ways;
>   for example, the final string could exceed the 63-character limit of a
>   DNS name. A label for which ToASCII fails cannot be used in an
>   internationalized domain name.

In your case a '' (blank) is not a valid domain name character, and you end up with this:

```
>>> '.f.de'.encode('idna')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/idna.py", line 164, in encode
    result.append(ToASCII(label))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/idna.py", line 73, in ToASCII
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long
```

If you change the domain name to 'a.f.de' it should not raise this exception.

Comment: yeah thanks man, this is exactly what is happening here. how can I raise Exception against this failure so that i can say that the url isnot valid?

Comment: You can catch the `UnicodeError` exception, just like you are catching the `httplib2.ServerNotFoundError` exception.

Comment: oh ok now i see. ``except UnicodeError``. thanks again.