# UnicodeError: label empty or too long

Tags: python-3.x, flask, unicode, ssh-tunnel

[I did go through [Burhan's answer here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103444/4993513)

This is what I am doing:

- I have a Flask API running on one of my remotes on the port 8891
- I created a tunnel on my Win machine as follows: `ssh -fN -L 8891:localhost:8891 <username>@<ip>`
- I am now using the `http://localhost:8891` endpoint for testing in my Win machine
- However, I get the following trace in my Flask debug logs on the remote machine:

[image]

Did I do something wrong here, cause I don't see any non-ASCII chars here

Comment: PS: Sorry about the code-as-image issue. Raised a [bug report here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333886/302377)

Comment: Then paste in notepad or something similar first @Dawny