# SQLAlchemy connection error: UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions

I'm using python3.7 and deploying a script in GCS. I've set up my run time env variables

```
USERNAME: xxxx,
PASSWORD: xxxx,
DATABASE: sample_db,
HOST_URL: project-name-services:asia-south1:database-name
```

I'm trying to execute a small query

```
QUERY = select * from sample_table where id between 20 and 30

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
# Equivalent URL:
# mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    drivername='mysql+pymysql',
    username=os.environ.get('USERNAME'),
    password=os.environ.get('PASSWORD'),
    database=os.environ.get('DATABASE'),
    host=os.environ.get('HOST_URL')
),
)

with db.connect() as conn:
     data = conn.execute(QUERY).fetchall()
     for i in data:
         print(i[1])
```

This is my small snippet running on GCS.

When I'm trying to run, I'm getting an error stating

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/lib/python3.7/encodings/idna.py", line 167, in encode raise UnicodeError("label too long") UnicodeError: label too long The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception

UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103444/5320906) - do you have non-ascii characters in your url?

Comment: As you can see in my run time variables, username and password are Alphanumeric, and host_url and db_name doesn't contain any ascii value. I dont get why it is giving me an error.